# Remove extra space from pattern

Tags: python-3.x, whitespace

This is a pattern for 180 degree triangle pattern in python

```
for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(n,-1,-1):
            if(j<=i):
                    print("#",end="")
            else:
                    print(" ",end="")
        print("")
```

**with this output is coming like this:**

```
      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
```

As you can see it has extra spaces
**What I want is:**

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(n,0,-1):
            if(j<=i):
                    print("#",end="")
            else:
                    print(" ",end="")
        print("")
```

Comment: it's removing the space on the side but adding a blank line on the very first line

Comment: since i have recently opened this account its showing this:"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".

Comment: yes i did it and if u find the question useful upvote it

Comment: @Rogue, just stick with your selected answer :) don't change it (for future cases)